# Reactive Extensions - Abort/Cancel an OnCompleted

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a Control that shows status messages; the control hides after an interval.  Here is the code that handles it:

```
private void ShowFor(TimeSpan? delay)
{
   Visible = true;

   if (!delay.HasValue) return; 

  // _pauseTimer is a MultipleAssignmentDisposable
  _pauseTimer.Disposable = Observable
     .Timer(delay.Value)
     .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
     .Subscribe(
          onNext:  _ => { /* do nothing */ },
     onCompleted: () => { Visible = false; },
         onError:  e => { /* what could possibly go wrong? */});
}
```

Show control, wait *n* seconds, hide control.  Easy peasy.

The problem is what to do when another message comes in before this timer has elapsed.  The second message shows, then the first timer expires and hides the control prematurely.

How can I "abort" the previous timer?  Dispose of the `pauseTimer.Disposable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate showing the control from hiding it. Assuming the messages are from an `IObservable<string> messages` (easy enough to set this up if they aren't currently) then subscribe to this and set the control visible with the message in the `OnNext`.

Separately, subscribe to the same stream with a throttle applied to hide the message after however long you need, e.g.:

```
messages.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
        .Subscribe(_ => control.Visible = false);
```

The throttle will emit only when a new message hasn't been seen for the desired delay.

To account for a varying delay, have your source of messages be a type that wraps the message and the severity. For simplicity here, I'll use a `Tuple<string, Timespan>`, but you could have an enum to represent severity and do something more elaborate. Throttle has an overload that varies it's duration by any stream. You could create the Throttle source based on the message duration:

```
// assuming messages is `Tuple<string, Timespan>`
var delayStream = messages.Throttle(
    messages.SelectMany(x => Observable.Timer(x.Item2)))
```

This would create a varying throttle based on the message severity, and you could use a very large (max) timeout for severe warnings - or just emit `Observable.Empty` for them instead of using the timer.

Note that under this scheme (and your description using a single control), a new message replaces a previous message though. A minor change would make this easy to handle - if your control displayed multiple messages and each carried an id, the `delayStream` could be used to decide which one needed removing from the current list.

Comment: I never even thought to make the messages a sequence in and of themselves; very clever.  The only issue I see is that messages vary by severity, and are not all displayed the same amount of time - and some have to be dismissed manually.  How would you compensate for this?

Comment: Edited to reflect your comment above and handle varying severity.

Answer (score 2):

Change `_pauseTimer` into a `SerialDisposable` rather than a `MultipleAssignmentDisposable`, then every time you do `_pauseTimer.Disposable = newDisposable` it will dispose of its current subscription be for subscribing to the next.